# Rectangle Wall collision in Java

Tags: java, collision, rectangles, pacman

I really could use some help in order to find a working solution for my game.
My game is almost done, but the walls in my game are still not working as they should.

I have tried to find a solution on the internet for this problem, but i still haven't found a simple way to stop a rectangle just before it will collide with a wall (another rectangle).

Right now i have implemented a collision detection between the player rectangle and the wall rectangle and then stopped it to move, but then it gets stuck inside a wall when it hits.

Want it to stop just before, so it still can move. The code i have done this with so far is here:

**Pacman Class**

```
public class Pacman {

private String pacmanup = "pacmanup.png";
private String pacmandown = "pacmandown.png";
private String pacmanleft = "pacmanleft.png";
private String pacmanright = "pacmanright.png";

private int dx;
private int dy;
private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;
private boolean visible;

private Image imageup;
private Image imagedown;
private Image imageleft;
private Image imageright;

public Pacman() {

    ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(pacmanup));
    imageup = i1.getImage();

    ImageIcon i2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(pacmandown));
    imagedown = i2.getImage();

    ImageIcon i3 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(pacmanleft));
    imageleft = i3.getImage();

    ImageIcon i4 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(pacmanright));
    imageright = i4.getImage();

    width = imageup.getWidth(null);
    height = imageup.getHeight(null);
    visible = true;
    x = 270;
    y = 189;

}

public int getDx() {
    return dx;
}

public void setDx(int dx) {
    this.dx = dx;
}

public int getDy() {
    return dy;
}

public void setDy(int dy) {
    this.dy = dy;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public Image getImageup() {
    return imageup;
}

public Image getImagedown() {
    return imagedown;
}

public Image getImageleft() {
    return imageleft;
}

public Image getImageright() {
    return imageright;
}

public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}

public void move() {

    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        dx = -2;
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        dx = 2;
        dy = 0;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        dx = 0;
        dy = -2;
    }

    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        dx = 0;
        dy = 2; 
    }
}
```

Here i have created a Rectangle getBounds method which i use to create an rectangle of the pacman and place an image over it.

**Barrier class / Wall class**

```
public class Barrier {

private String barrier = "barrier.png";

private int x;
private int y;
private int width;
private int height;
private boolean visible;
private Image image;

public Barrier(int x, int y) {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(barrier));
    image = ii.getImage();      
    width = image.getWidth(null);
    height = image.getHeight(null);
    visible = true;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public boolean isVisible() {
    return visible;
}

public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
    this.visible = visible;
}

public Image getImage() {
    return image;
}

public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
}
```

This class also have the Rectangle getBounds class which i use to detect collision.

The last code i show is how i do the collision detection so far:

**Code inside Board class**

```
Rectangle r3 = pacman.getBounds();

 for (int j = 0; j<barriers.size(); j++) {
        Barrier b = (Barrier) barriers.get(j);
        Rectangle r4 = b.getBounds();

        if (r3.intersects(r4)) {
            System.out.println("Wall hit");
            pacman.setDx(0);
            pacman.setDy(0);
        }
    }
```

Well, what i do, if there is a collision between r3 and r4, i gonna set Dx and Dy to 0.. what i want to find another solution so it detect for collision but i wont get stuck inside a wall, but i don't know how to :/

Hope someone will help.

Comment: I guess your Problem is in the onKeyPressed method why do you move always 2 fields in one direction instead of just one? btw did you lost the implements of the keylistener?

Comment: Nono.. i have made the implements in my board class, with a keyadapter and then i just run the method in my pacman class like this:

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   pacman.keyPressed(e);
  }

Comment: You need to test whether the move would produce a collision *before* you actually commit it (better), or else track the the previous position and revert to it when you detect a collision.  Your code can only detect a collision that has already happened.  Possibly it would suffice to set `dx` to `-dx` and `dy` to `-dy` instead of zeroing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two approaches you can follow.  One is ugly but easier, the other one requires a deeper redesign of your classes.

### 1) Ugly/Simple Approach

In the ugly one, you keep moving your guy before doing the collision checks. Simply move your pacman back to the point where it was not stuck. You accomplish that by inverting the last directions used:

**Code inside Board class**

Change your reaction in case you find a collision: just walk the same distance, backwards.

```
    if (r3.intersects(r4)) {
        System.out.println("Wall hit, move back");
        pacman.setDx(-pacman.getDx());
        pacman.setDy(-pacman.getDy());
        // Possibly need to call move() here again.
        pacman.move();
        break;
    }
```

Ugly, but should work.
Not recommended to coding perfectionists with OCD and heart disease, though.

### 2) Redesign

In this approach, you test the position pacman will occupy before doing any actual moves. If that spot is not into any barrier, then perform the movement for real.

**Code inside Pacman class**

Add this method, so that you can check for collisions against the new bounds.

```
public Rectangle getOffsetBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x + dx, y + dy, width, height);
}
```

**Code inside Board class**

```
// Strip the call to pacman.move() prior to this point.

Rectangle r3 = pacman.getOffsetBounds(); // Check against the candidate position.

for (int j = 0; j<barriers.size(); j++) {
    Barrier b = (Barrier) barriers.get(j);
    Rectangle r4 = b.getBounds();

    if (r3.intersects(r4)) {
        System.out.println("Wall hit");
        pacman.setDx(0);
        pacman.setDy(0);
        // Quit the loop. It's pointless to check other barriers once we hit one.
        break;
    }
}
// Now we're good to move only in case there's no barrier on our way.
pacman.move();
```

Particularly I prefer this approach, but it's up to you to pick the best one.

Comment: Well... i'm going to try both approaches, and learn from this. Will let you know if it works well :)

Comment: Thank you very much... i used the way number 2.. Redesign method. work, the other didn't :)

Comment: Glad to help. Way number 1 should work, though. Have you included a call to move as suggested in the comments?  Anyway, I only included the approach number 1 there for learning purposes, it was not really a good option at all, since it would actually move pacman forth and back everytime it smacked a barrier. Now I'm curious to see how you're implementing them ghosts :)